# Magento 2 setup:upgrade command gives MySQL DB permission error

Tags: database, magento2.4.3

When I try to perform `setup:upgrade` always getting the below error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable), query was:

CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_product_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_category_product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
END
```

I have tried setting `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` and granting all the access to the corresponding MySQL user. It will work for some time but again after some hours, the problem starts automatically. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Try this https://www.technodba.com/2018/11/error-code-1419-you-do-not-have-super.html

Answer (score 0):

You must check if RDS MySQL has triggers disabled or enabled, because the latest gen of RDS MySQL has triggers disabled and you must to enable these.

Kindly check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-privileges) post to how to set pervillages and triggers in RDS Web console.